# python regex to match file name but get None

Tags: python, regex

I have a few files in the folder and I want to find out the content and match its file name. But when I use re.search to achieve my goal I can only get ‘None’. Anyone could help?

```
import re
xe = r'D:\ABC\cc123.xml'
re.search('cc*?.xml', xe)
```

Comment: also, for future reference, you can use something like [pythex](https://pythex.org/) to test your regular expressions, and [python regex documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) for syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Though there is an accepted answer, I don't feel the answer is clear for other people, and there is still room to improve, so I added a new answer here)

The problem is simply OP is using a wrong regex: `cc*?.xml`

`*` means any occurrence of the *preceding* token (which means `c` in your case)
`*?` is a reluctant match any occurrence.
`.` means any character

Which means what you are trying to do is match a string which is:

- a `c`
- followed by any occurrence of c
- followed by any character
- followed by `xml`

Example of matching strings are `c.xml` `ccccccAxml` etc.

What you were trying to do, I believe is

```
cc.*?\.xml
```

which means matching

- `cc`
- `.*?` : followed by any occurrence of any character, matching as few as possible
- `\.`  : followed by a dot  (note the difference of `\.` vs `.`)
- followed by `xml`

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this with a small tweak?

```
import re
xe = 'D:\ABC\cc123.xml'
print (re.search('cc.*?.xml', xe).group())
```

output:

```
cc123.xml
```